# Scala Lifting to a thunk

Tags: scala, thunk

I have a function that wraps the result of another function in a Promise. I wanted to promote this into a lift function so that I could sort of re-use it elsewhere. Here are the original definitions:

```
val abc = Promise[MyType]()
try {
  val suck = abc.success(someOtherFunction(intParam1, intParam2))
} catch {
  case ex: Exception => p.failure(ex)
}
```

So what I eventually did was the following:

```
def myLiftFunc[X](x: X) (op: => X): Promise[X] = {
  val p = Promise[X]()

  try {
    p.success(op)
  } catch {
    case NonFatal(ex) =>
    p.failure(ex)
  }
  p
}
```

How can I re-use this? I mean, the second argument that I pass in should be a thunk so that I could just pass in any function body irrespective of the parameters that function body would require!

When I call the lifted function as:

```
myLiftFunc(someOtherFunction(intParam1, intParam2))
```

This is of type `Int => Promise[Int]`, where the `someOtherFunction` returns an `Int`. I just want `Promise[Int]` when I call `myLiftFunc`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in the `Promise.fromTry` method.  That method uses the `Try` idiom from `scala.util`, which is a useful structure that allows you to treat a `try...catch` statement more like a traditional constructs:

```
Promise.fromTry { Try { someOtherFunction(intParam1, intParam2) } }
```

If you wanted to right your own helper (so that the `Try` part is unnecessary, you could try something like:

```
def myLiftFunc[X](op: => X): Promise[X] = Promise.fromTry(Try(op))
```

This would allow you to do:

```
myLiftFunc { /*arbitrary logic*/ }
myLiftFunc(1 + 4).future.value.get //Success(5)
myLiftFunc(1/0).future.value.get //Failure(java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero)
```